# Video Streaming on network using java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, streaming, server, rtsp

I am developing a networking java application. I wanted to stream a video from network (maybe using sockets). I search on the internet but I didnt find any working server and client code to stream video from a server to a client.
Can anyone find streaming server and client or code a simple program so that I can understand how streaming is done using java.

PS. I fount an assignment related to this on internet. But it has error and some methods are also unimplemented. If you can remove errors and complete the methods it will also be helpful..
http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp3310/2004/Labs/lab6/lab5.html

Answer (score 3):

See: [Any simple (and up to date) Java frameworks for embedding movies within a Swing Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440152/any-simple-and-up-to-date-java-frameworks-for-embedding-movies-within-a-swing), just refer to the JavaFX only code sample (you don't need any Swing code).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VideoPlayerExample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final MediaPlayer oracleVid = new MediaPlayer(
      new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv")
    );
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new MediaView(oracleVid)), 540, 208));
    stage.show();

    oracleVid.play();
  }
}
```

So, encode your video to a [format understood by JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) (e.g. h264 encoded mp4) and place it on a http server and you can load the video data over http from your JavaFX client.  Ensure that your client is a [certified system configuration for media playback using JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

That is probably sufficient for what you need.

---

If you need something a bit more fancy, JavaFX also supports [http live streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming), which you can read up on and see if you need (which you probably don't).  I don't have instructions on setting up a http live streaming server, nor a link to somewhere on the internet on how to do that (you would have to do your own research on that if you want to go that route).

---

Also, note, I converted the [mjpeg player lab assignment you reference in your question](http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp3310/2004/Labs/lab6/lab5.html) to JavaFX to answer the question: [Display RTP MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721917/display-rtp-mjpeg).  It is useful if you want to understand at a low level how such video playback is done.  However, I would not recommend using this method for your video playback for a production project - instead just use the built-in JavaFX MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basic code: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo.java

but I changed it to:

```
package Pasban;

/**
 *
 * @modified by Pasban
 */
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoResampler;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Utils;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.VideoImage;
import java.awt.Dimension;

/**
 * Takes a media container, finds the first video stream,
 * decodes that stream, and then plays the audio and video.
 *
 * This code does a VERY coarse job of matching time-stamps, and thus
 * the audio and video will float in and out of slight sync.  Getting
 * time-stamps syncing-up with audio is very system dependent and left
 * as an exercise for the reader.
 * 
 * @author aclarke
 *
 */
public class DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo {

    /**
     * The audio line we'll output sound to; it'll be the default audio device on your system if available
     */
    private static SourceDataLine mLine;
    /**
     * The window we'll draw the video on.
     * 
     */
    private static VideoImage mScreen = null;
    private static long mSystemVideoClockStartTime;
    private static long mFirstVideoTimestampInStream;

    /**
     * Takes a media container (file) as the first argument, opens it,
     * plays audio as quickly as it can, and opens up a Swing window and displays
     * video frames with <i>roughly</i> the right timing.
     *  
     * @param args Must contain one string which represents a filename
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";

        // Let's make sure that we can actually convert video pixel formats.
        if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for this demo to work");
        }

        // Create a Xuggler container object
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();

        // Open up the container
        if (container.open("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4", IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);
        }

        // query how many streams the call to open found
        int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

        // and iterate through the streams to find the first audio stream
        int videoStreamId = -1;
        IStreamCoder videoCoder = null;
        int audioStreamId = -1;
        IStreamCoder audioCoder = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) {
            // Find the stream object
            IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
            // Get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
            IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

            if (videoStreamId == -1 && coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                videoStreamId = i;
                videoCoder = coder;
            } else if (audioStreamId == -1 && coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                audioStreamId = i;
                audioCoder = coder;
            }
        }
        if (videoStreamId == -1 && audioStreamId == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not find audio or video stream in container: " + filename);
        }

        /*
         * Check if we have a video stream in this file.  If so let's open up our decoder so it can
         * do work.
         */
        IVideoResampler resampler = null;
        if (videoCoder != null) {
            if (videoCoder.open() < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: " + filename);
            }

            if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) {
                // if this stream is not in BGR24, we're going to need to
                // convert it.  The VideoResampler does that for us.
                resampler = IVideoResampler.make(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24,
                        videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder.getPixelType());

                openJavaVideo(videoCoder);


                if (resampler == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("could not create color space resampler for: " + filename);
                }
            }
            /*
             * And once we have that, we draw a window on screen
             */
        }

        if (audioCoder != null) {
            if (audioCoder.open() < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: " + filename);
            }

            /*
             * And once we have that, we ask the Java Sound System to get itself ready.
             */
            try {
                openJavaSound(audioCoder);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("unable to open sound device on your system when playing back container: " + filename);
            }
        }


        /*
         * Now, we start walking through the container looking at each packet.
         */
        IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
        mFirstVideoTimestampInStream = Global.NO_PTS;
        mSystemVideoClockStartTime = 0;
        while (container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0) {
            /*
             * Now we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to our video stream
             */
            if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId) {
                /*
                 * We allocate a new picture to get the data out of Xuggler
                 */
                IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(),
                        videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());

                /*
                 * Now, we decode the video, checking for any errors.
                 * 
                 */
                int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, 0);
                if (bytesDecoded < 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);
                }

                /*
                 * Some decoders will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
                 * a full video picture yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
                 * got a complete picture from the decoder
                 */
                if (picture.isComplete()) {
                    IVideoPicture newPic = picture;
                    /*
                     * If the resampler is not null, that means we didn't get the video in BGR24 format and
                     * need to convert it into BGR24 format.
                     */
                    if (resampler != null) {
                        // we must resample
                        newPic = IVideoPicture.make(resampler.getOutputPixelFormat(), picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
                        if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("could not resample video from: " + filename);
                        }
                    }
                    if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("could not decode video as BGR 24 bit data in: " + filename);
                    }

                    long delay = millisecondsUntilTimeToDisplay(newPic);
                    // if there is no audio stream; go ahead and hold up the main thread.  We'll end
                    // up caching fewer video pictures in memory that way.
                    try {
                        if (delay > 0) {
                            Thread.sleep(delay);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // And finally, convert the picture to an image and display it

                    mScreen.setImage(Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic));
                }
            } else if (packet.getStreamIndex() == audioStreamId) {
                /*
                 * We allocate a set of samples with the same number of channels as the
                 * coder tells us is in this buffer.
                 * 
                 * We also pass in a buffer size (1024 in our example), although Xuggler
                 * will probably allocate more space than just the 1024 (it's not important why).
                 */
                IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(1024, audioCoder.getChannels());

                /*
                 * A packet can actually contain multiple sets of samples (or frames of samples
                 * in audio-decoding speak).  So, we may need to call decode audio multiple
                 * times at different offsets in the packet's data.  We capture that here.
                 */
                int offset = 0;

                /*
                 * Keep going until we've processed all data
                 */
                while (offset < packet.getSize()) {
                    int bytesDecoded = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, packet, offset);
                    if (bytesDecoded < 0) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);
                    }
                    offset += bytesDecoded;
                    /*
                     * Some decoder will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
                     * a full set of samples yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
                     * got a complete set of samples from the decoder
                     */
                    if (samples.isComplete()) {
                        // note: this call will block if Java's sound buffers fill up, and we're
                        // okay with that.  That's why we have the video "sleeping" occur
                        // on another thread.
                        playJavaSound(samples);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /*
                 * This packet isn't part of our video stream, so we just silently drop it.
                 */
                do {
                } while (false);
            }

        }
        /*
         * Technically since we're exiting anyway, these will be cleaned up by 
         * the garbage collector... but because we're nice people and want
         * to be invited places for Christmas, we're going to show how to clean up.
         */
        if (videoCoder != null) {
            videoCoder.close();
            videoCoder = null;
        }
        if (audioCoder != null) {
            audioCoder.close();
            audioCoder = null;
        }
        if (container != null) {
            container.close();
            container = null;
        }
        closeJavaSound();
        closeJavaVideo();
    }

    private static long millisecondsUntilTimeToDisplay(IVideoPicture picture) {
        /**
         * We could just display the images as quickly as we decode them, but it turns
         * out we can decode a lot faster than you think.
         * 
         * So instead, the following code does a poor-man's version of trying to
         * match up the frame-rate requested for each IVideoPicture with the system
         * clock time on your computer.
         * 
         * Remember that all Xuggler IAudioSamples and IVideoPicture objects always
         * give timestamps in Microseconds, relative to the first decoded item.  If
         * instead you used the packet timestamps, they can be in different units depending
         * on your IContainer, and IStream and things can get hairy quickly.
         */
        long millisecondsToSleep = 0;
        if (mFirstVideoTimestampInStream == Global.NO_PTS) {
            // This is our first time through
            mFirstVideoTimestampInStream = picture.getTimeStamp();
            // get the starting clock time so we can hold up frames
            // until the right time.
            mSystemVideoClockStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            millisecondsToSleep = 0;
        } else {
            long systemClockCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo = systemClockCurrentTime - mSystemVideoClockStartTime;
            // compute how long for this frame since the first frame in the stream.
            // remember that IVideoPicture and IAudioSamples timestamps are always in MICROSECONDS,
            // so we divide by 1000 to get milliseconds.
            long millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo = (picture.getTimeStamp() - mFirstVideoTimestampInStream) / 1000;
            final long millisecondsTolerance = 50; // and we give ourselfs 50 ms of tolerance
            millisecondsToSleep = (millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo
                    - (millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo + millisecondsTolerance));
        }
        return millisecondsToSleep;
    }

    /**
     * Opens a Swing window on screen.
     */
    /**
     * Forces the swing thread to terminate; I'm sure there is a right
     * way to do this in swing, but this works too.
     */
    private static void closeJavaVideo() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void openJavaSound(IStreamCoder aAudioCoder) throws LineUnavailableException {
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(aAudioCoder.getSampleRate(),
                (int) IAudioSamples.findSampleBitDepth(aAudioCoder.getSampleFormat()),
                aAudioCoder.getChannels(),
                true, /* xuggler defaults to signed 16 bit samples */
                false);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        mLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        /**
         * if that succeeded, try opening the line.
         */
        mLine.open(audioFormat);
        /**
         * And if that succeed, start the line.
         */
        mLine.start();


    }

    private static void playJavaSound(IAudioSamples aSamples) {
        /**
         * We're just going to dump all the samples into the line.
         */
        byte[] rawBytes = aSamples.getData().getByteArray(0, aSamples.getSize());
        mLine.write(rawBytes, 0, aSamples.getSize());
    }

    private static void closeJavaSound() {
        if (mLine != null) {
            /*
             * Wait for the line to finish playing
             */
            mLine.drain();
            /*
             * Close the line.
             */
            mLine.close();
            mLine = null;
        }
    }

    private static void openJavaVideo(IStreamCoder videoCoder) {
        mScreen = new VideoImage();
        mScreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight()));
        mScreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Things I changed:

```
private static void openJavaVideo(IStreamCoder videoCoder) {
        mScreen = new VideoImage();
        mScreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight()));
        mScreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
```

Moved *openJavaVideo* method into videoStream detector:

```
openJavaVideo(videoCoder);
```

Changed the first part of the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";

        // Let's make sure that we can actually convert video pixel formats.
        if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for this demo to work");
        }

        // Create a Xuggler container object
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();

        // Open up the container
        if (container.open("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4", IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);
        }
```

Actually, the important part was:

```
if (container.open("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4", IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Xuggle is/was one of the best:

[Streaming video with Xuggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555000/streaming-video-with-xuggler)

Right now I don;t have a complete project, but I believe it had an example with its demo files.

Search google for xuggle video streaming demo or similar keywords with Xuggler. It is easy to use and support most of the known formats as it wraps FFMPEG with itself.

Comment: I didnt find any demo using which I can implement that program. Can you find one for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came to another idea it may worth trying.

1. Create a JavaFX application.
2. Add a web browser into it, check **webengine**
3. create a template webpage which it contains a html player, or load the page in your server where it accept file id, then create a page that create a player for that file, similar to youtube, then auto play it.

This will be much better idea it you could do it.

There are sample codes for webengine and javaFX. Once you loaded a page, say, youtube or vimeo and played a video there, then sky is the limit :)